# Will browser isolation solution protect our enterprise from Flash and JavaScript exploits and fileless malware?

Tags: malware, web-browser, exploit, flash, browser-hijacking

Since we didn't see any pentest done to bypass on such solution, we don't really know if it worth purchasing such type of solution. Will this really protect us from Flash and JavaScript exploits, fileless malware and other related hacks?

Comment: yes it will protect you because it's not your "computer" getting attacked. if it goes down, you just reconnect to a different instance...

Answer (score 1):

This will add another line of defense which will provide a better (but not perfect) protection against some attacks but not against others. It will probably be mostly effective against an attacker trying to break out of the browser into the system, although sandbox techniques used in modern browsers like Chrome already provide a good (but not perfect) protection in these cases.

But it will not help against Javascript-based or Flash-based attacks in general, i.e. it will not help against Cross-Site-Scripting or CSRF or cross-site flash attacks. These are not attacks which try to break out of the browser but instead work inside the browser and thus also inside the isolated browser.  A properly isolated browser might though prevent these attacks to affect your internal network. Browser isolation will also not help against social attacks like phishing for credentials.